# How to write a LINQ If Else statement that does not return any value(even a null) if check evaluates to false?

Tags: c#, linq

I am writing a LINQ query that is performing a join on two tables, Artists and Groups (musical groups). The query is checking for artists that belong to a specific group and returning them as a list which I will iterate through and print to the console.

The problem is that I'm forced to write an else statement together with my if check and return something. I'm returning null currently, but want to skip that step entirely as the null values show up (as empty values) when I'm printing out my list. I've tried to use the `.Distinct()` method but it will still leave one null in my list.

```
var Beatles = Artists.Join(
    Groups, 
    artist => artist.GroupId, 
    group => group.Id, 
    (artist, group) =>
    {
        if(artist.GroupId == 1)
        {
            return artist.ArtistName;
        }
        else{
            return ;
        }
     })
    .ToList()
    .Distinct();

if(Beatles.Any())
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("Here are all the members of the Beatles");
    foreach(var person in Beatles)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(person);
    }
};
```

Comment: Use `.Where` to filter elements.

Comment: I think you want to use `GroupJoin` instead of `Join` which lets you match a set of "right" elements with each "left" element.  The set in your case would have 1 or 0 elements.  This is like the difference between `SelectMany` and `Select`

Comment: The issue is that your `join` `Func` must return the same type in both the `if` case and the `else` case.  You could use the [Maybe monad](https://smellegantcode.wordpress.com/2008/12/11/the-maybe-monad-in-c/) to handle making the return type consistent whether there is or isn't anything to return.

Comment: Can a group have no members? That wouldn't make logical sense. I'd guess there's a data model problem and fixing that will let you come at the Linq query from a better angle. How are your tables defined?

Comment: The Artists and Groups are JsonData files which are translated to Lists.

Comment: Why are you doing a join at all? Surely the query you want is `Artists.Where(a => a.GroupId == 1).Select(a => a.ArtistName).Distinct().ToList();` , no?  You're not using any property of `group` in your join projection, so why are you joining against it at all?

Comment: And why are you calling Distinct *after* ToList? That seems like a strange thing to do; you get all the down sides of generating the list with none of the up sides.

Comment: Great questions. I'm learning LINQ right now and have a fair bit of learning to do it seems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply use `Where` to filter.

```
var Beatles =
(from a in Artists
    join g in Groups on a.GroupId equals g.Id
    where a.GroupId == 1
    select a.ArtistName).ToList();
```

And I couldn't figure out why are you applying join, it is completely redundant in this case.

```
var Beatles = Artists.Where(x => x.GroupId == 1).Select(x => x.ArtistName).ToList();
```

> I've tried to use the .Distinct() method but it will still leave one
>   null in my list.

I assume that you use `Distinct` because of filtering the `null` values. But It is not purpose of `Distinct`. It is completely misusage.

Comment: I'm learning LINQ at the moment and was directed to use .join(). Now I know of a better way to do it. Thanks

Comment: I thought that Distinct() filters out values that aren't unique. Is that not true?

Comment: @MBaka: Make sure you understand the semantics of a join; don't just use them blindly.  It should be clear that `from x in xs from y in ys where x.foo == y.bar select f(x,y)` and `from x in xs join y in ys on x.foo equals y.bar select f(x,y)` are *logically* the same thing and produce the same results. It should also be clear that the former is potentially more expensive than the latter. If either of those things are not clear then *stop what you're doing and think about it until it becomes clear.*  **A join is logically an equality filter on a cartesian product.**

Comment: @MBaka: Stormcloak's point is that you're complaining that Distinct is leaving *one null* in the list. That's exactly what it should be doing; it's leaving *a unique null* in the list. If it left *two* nulls or *zero* nulls then it would be doing the wrong thing.

Comment: I understand that, which is why I'm attempting to find another solution that does not rely on Distinct. I don't want there to be any null values so while Distinct was the closest thing I could come up with it still doesn't solve the problem.